# What is the probability of person $i$ to be served by machine $j$?

Tags: probability

Assume that time is discrete and divided into $T$ periods. We have $m$ persons and $n$ machines. At any period $t\in\{1,2,\ldots,T\}$, every machine can serve at most one person. Further, when person $i$ is assigned to machine $j$, it will be served for $X_i$ periods and we assume that $\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i\leq T$. Now, fix any person $i$ and any machine $j$. Without any additional information, can we calculate the probability that person $i$ will be served by machine $j$? If no, then what kind of information is missing? (Maybe we have to assume that $X_i$ are random variables and specify their distributions.)